# How to change the symbol databases folder of the VisualAssist X?

Tags: visual-assist

Does anybody know if it is possible to change the folder, where the VisualAssist X stores its symbol databases?

By default it is in

```
<%APPDATA%>\VisualAssist
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on the version of VA and Visual Studio.  See [this article in the Whole Tomato support knowledge base](http://support.wholetomato.com/default.asp?W332).

Comment: Thanks! My profile is smaller now. The version is 10.5.1738 with Visual Studio 2008